# Custom map (virtual world) in Google Maps

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

Is it possible to use Google Maps API to show a virtual world ?

By virtual world, I mean not the real world map but a completely created map.

The only informations I found is for changing graphics of tiles or for adding some informations like shape or annotations but always in the same real world map.

Comment: Explain how replacing the tiles with a fantasy map isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: Because tiles are just graphics, I want use maps api also to calculate distances or itineraries.

Comment: For complete customization you might want to look at [OpenStreetMap](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) as [the backing dataset](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) handles [POI and path routes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features).

Comment: Take a look at [Tile Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay).